# Which desktop file is my application using?

Tags: gnome, icons, .desktop, desktop-icons

When I click on `Applications` from Gnome Shell (Ubuntu 18.04), I only see one "Desktop Icon" for the application Emacs.

I want to change the arguments that this desktop icon launches with.

However, I have no convenient way to figure out which desktop icon that is, or which commands it runs.  When I clikc on "Show Details", I just get an error message in Ubuntu Software that says: "Cannot find emacs_desktop.desktop".

(Note: If Ubuntu / Gnone really had their UX down, I would be able to see this from a right click menu similar to "preferences" tab on windows).

[image]

So then  I the command line I try: `locate emacs.desktop` and I get:

```
/snap/emacs/232/meta/gui/emacs.desktop
/snap/emacs/232/usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop
/snap/emacs/232/usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop.bak
/snap/emacs/232/usr/share/emacs/26.3/etc/emacs.desktop
/snap/emacs/255/meta/gui/emacs.desktop
/snap/emacs/255/usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop
/snap/emacs/255/usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop.bak
/snap/emacs/255/usr/share/emacs/26.3/etc/emacs.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/emacs_emacs.desktop
```

**How can I easily figure out where an application's desktop file is, or which desktop file it is using?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the exact `Name=` field in the `.desktop` file. So, I expect the following command to display the name of the `.desktop` file that defines the `Emacs` "application":

```
find / -name "*.desktop" 2>/dev/null -exec grep -l "Name *= *Emacs" '{}' \;
```

Note the case sensitivity.